# ANTLR grammar expression evaluation for token which can be available zero or 1 time

Tags: antlr, grammar

I have a combined ANTLR grammar, which shall look out for specific tokens / token combinations. Some tokes can be available zero or 1 time. 
I want to store a "found" or "not found" value to a hashmap for those tokens. I already know, how to do this in the case the token is available. But how can I do it for a token that has not been found.
Following examples shows it very simplified:

```
grammar Expr;

@header {
import java.util.HashMap;
}

@members {
HashMap<String,String> memory = new HashMap<String,String>();
}

statements: ONE  
      (WS TWO {memory.put("two","found");})? 
      WS THREE EOF;    

ONE: 'one';
TWO: 'two';
THREE: 'three';
WS: ' ';
```

Is there a possibility to find out directly within this grammar, that "TWO" was not found and therefore put a different value to the HashMap?

```
memory.put("two","not found");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to find out directly within this grammar, that "TWO" was not found and therefore put a different value to the HashMap?

Sure, like this:

```
statements
 : ONE WS ( TWO WS THREE EOF {memory.put("two","found");}
          | THREE EOF        {memory.put("two","not found");}
          )
 ;
```

### EDIT

Or if you have more optional tokens (`TWO`, `THREE` and `FOUR` are optional), do:

```
statements
 : ONE (WS TWO memory.put("two","found");     | memory.put("two","not found");) 
       (WS THREE memory.put("three","found"); | memory.put("three","not found");) 
       (WS FOUR memory.put("four","found");   | memory.put("four","not found");) 
   EOF
 ;
```

Or something like this should also work:

```
statements
 : ONE (WS TWO)? (WS THREE)? (WS FOUR)?
   {
     memory.put("two", $TWO.text == null ? "not found" : "found");
     memory.put("three", $THREE.text == null ? "not found" : "found");
     memory.put("four", $FOUR.text == null ? "not found" : "found");
   }
 ;
```

Comment: So the solution is to split up all single combinations. This might blow up the grammar, if you have a lot of single expressions that can appears once or never in a row. Is there another possibility?

Comment: thanks a lot, I was not aware of the possibility of this more or less "empty expression".